# if test on [undefined]

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement, conditional-statements, undefined

`[undefined] === true` returns `false`.

```js
if ([undefined]) { 
  console.log('is true') 
}
```

prints `is true` to the console.

How does this make sense?

Comment: Please add a tag for the language that you use (javascript?)

Comment: Try `Boolean([undefined])`

Comment: @John: Slick! Thanks! That's what's performed for a conditional test, I guess, then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using three equals signs is used to determine if the value and the type are the same; that's why `1 == true` but `1 !== true`.

Your if-statement tries to evaluate `[undefined]`, but only to the extent to whether it's truthy or falsy. `[undefined]` is a non-empty array, so it is truthy and evaluates to `true` in an if-statement. However, `[undefined]` is not a boolean on its own, so that's why `[undefined] === true` evaluates to false.

This does a job of explaining what's going on somewhat: https://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/

Comment: I should have written my question differently. My new/real question is why if `[undefined] == true` returns `false` that the `if ([undefined]) {}` branch would execute. How is "truthiness" determined if not by comparison to `true`?

Comment: @fuzzybear3965 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy "All values are truthy unless they are defined as falsy (i.e., except for false, 0, "", null, undefined, and NaN)."

Comment: That's a good start. But, it doesn't explain why `[undefined] == true` would return `false`, then, since it's apparently truthy.

Comment: Because truthy is not the same thing as "equals true." When you do explicit boolean comparisons, you may get different results from relying on truthiness. That's one of the big pitfalls you have to be aware of in JS programming.

Comment: I did have an issue in my answer where I implied that truthy is the same as true; I just removed that bit. But yeah...JavaScript can be fun in that regard.

Comment: Thanks, @ChrisForrence. That was a good reference. Thanks, also, for amending your original answer; it's clearer now. This issue is closed. Man, JavaScript makes booleans complicated.

Comment: Thanks, @JohnMontgomery for your input, too. (I can only @ one user per comment.)